# Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible matrices and $B=A^{-1}$. Is the matrix $AB - BA$ a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How could we prove this? I tried transposing the whole thing, and then I kinda got stuck there.

$(AB-BA)^{T} = B^TA^T - A^TB^T = (A^{-1})^TA^T-A^T(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}A^T-A^T(A^T)^{-1}$

I thought of making something of

$AB - BA = I - I = 0$

since they are invertible. How would I finish this proof?

Comment: Zero matrix is symmetric so $AB-BA$ is symmetric

Comment: @LevBahn Yeah fair enough. So simple can't believe I missed it lol. Thanks!